# Sorting Cards played in each trick according to a certain set of rules

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

Say I have a tuple of cards. Each of them represents a card played by a player.

```
('9D',   '9S',   '3S',   '0D')
Player0 Player1 Player2 Player3
```

I wish to find the winning card in it and record who is the winner.

And the rules for deciding the winner is quite messy...

First I have a trump card used to determine the trump suit.
Say I have `2D` as a trump card. Then the suit **Diamond** becomes trump suit.

Secondly, the first card in the tuple means the leading card and all other players should attempt to follow the suit of that card, if not then the card being played by that player virtually lost.

I wish to compare the face value of those cards. **0** stands for **10** in this case. The card with the highest value and also follows the suit wins. Below is my code and I have not gotten even close to the goal. I know the what is the goal for me to achieve. But my code definitely contains redundancy. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Any advice on how to implement a neat solution are greatly appreciated.

My code:

```
    tricks = ('9D', '9S', '3S', '0D')
    counter = 1
    for i in tricks:
        while counter < len(i):
            if max_score[1] == deck_top[1]:
                # Check if it is in trump suit. 
                if int(i[counter-1][0]) < int(i[counter][0]):
                    # Compare face value
                if i[counter-1][0] == i[counter][0]:
                    # Compare the suit.
                    if i[counter][1] == i[counter][1]:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a list comprehension, max() and a custom sort key. I'm not positive I correctly understand the problem but I interpreted it as: the winner is the card with the highest value and the same suit as the trump card

```
def getCardValue(inputVal): #custom key func that calculates zero as a 10
    num = int(inputVal[:-1])
    if num == 0:
        return 10
    return num

trumpCard = '2D'
tricks = ('9D', '9S', '3S', '0D')
potentialWinners = [x for x in tricks if x[-1] == trumpCard[-1]] #remove cards that don't have same suit as trumpCard
print(max(potentialWinners, key=getCardValue)) #get max card value while calculating zero as 10
```

## Modifications to getCardValue to use J, Q, K, A

```
def getCardValue(inputVal): #custom key func that calculates zero as a 10
    inputVal = inputVal[:-1]
    specialValues = {"J": 11, "Q": 12, "K": 13, "A": 14}
    if inputVal in specialValues.keys():
        return specialValues[inputVal]

    num = int(inputVal)
    if num == 0:
        return 10
    return num
```

## Modifications to get the index of the winner

Change the last two lines to:

```
winner = max(potentialWinners, key=getCardValue) #get max card value while calculating zero as 10
print("player", tricks.index(winner), "wins with the card", winner)
```

Comment: Also if I wish to represent J as 11, Queen as 12, King as 13 and so on, the if statement would be able to do that in the getcardValue function right? Thank you for the prompt response!

Comment: Yes you could do that, you could also just make cards 10D 11D or 9999D. It gets the suit just by checking the last character, it gets the value by getting everything EXCEPT the last character

Comment: Sure and your interpretation of the question is spot on!

Comment: Oh and also, if I want to keep track of who won this trick, say I need the index of that card, wouldn't remove the card causing the index being changed? Sorry if I didn't clear the confusion in my post...  EDIT: Or would it be possible for me to use the card value and get the index back from the original tuple?

Comment: Tuples are immutable so they never get changed. You can use tricks.index(winner) where winner is what I printed

Comment: Thank you kind sir this definitely helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a potential solution, if I understand the problem correctly..

```
trump_suit = 'S'
cards = ('9D', '9S', '3S', '0D')

suit_to_follow = cards[0][1]

leading_player = None
leading_value = None  # (is_trump, value)
for player, card in enumerate(cards):
    value = int(card[0]) or 10
    suit = card[1]
    is_trump = suit == trump_suit

    current_value = (is_trump, value)
    if is_trump or suit == suit_to_follow:
        if current_value > leading_value:
            leading_player = player
            leading_value = current_value

print 'winning player:', leading_player
```

Comment: So if I have J Q K A, can such string be represented as values? Or do I need a map of all the values to do so?